# Factory Girl with string attribute keys instead of symbols?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

When I call `Factory.attributes_for(:some_class)` I obviously get back a hash of attributes for that class.

```
{ :attribute_one => "hello", :attribute_two => "goodbye" }
```

Is there a convenient way to retrieve this attributes hash with string keys rather than symbols?

```
{ "attribute_one" => "hello", "attribute_two" => "goodbye" }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[xdazz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/762073/xdazz)'s answer is a good option but if you want to actually convert the keys to strings instead of accessing the hash indifferently you can use [`stringify_keys`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-stringify_keys)

```
Factory.attributes_for(:some_class).stringify_keys
```

Answer (score 7):

This will let you access the value by both symbol and string key.

```
Factory.attributes_for(:some_class).with_indifferent_access
```